# Best Simple Way to Share a Git Repository over LAN

Tags: windows, git, version-control, file-sharing

I need to share a large git repository (>3GB in total, .git folder is ~1.1GB) as Windows Shared Folder over LAN with my colleagues. But they found it is really slow to clone and push/pull -- i.e. waits ~30min before the clone starts, and suspended ~5min before any push/pull starts.

Does everyone know any methods to reduce the latency or better way to share the repo?

P.S. I don't want to setup a Gitlab because it's too complicated.

Comment: How long does it take to copy the equivalent amount of data across your network, just using normal windows explorer?

Comment: The thing is that every pull/push takes too much time to wait before the pull/push really starts.

Comment: The LAN is very stable. Copying large file is up to 30MB/s. The repo contains too many small files, so it takes long to copy as file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your git repo is very big, you can **bundle the whole git repo or part of commits among your colleagues sharing**.

Bundle the whole repo: `git bundle create repo.bundle --all`

Bundle a branch: `git bundle create repo.bundle branchname`

Bundle some commits: `git bundle create commits.bundle branchname ^commit`

For the one who apply the bundled commits to his local repo, he can verify the bundle file by `git bundle verify /path/to/bundle/file`.

More details, you can refer [Git's Little Bundle of Joy](https://www.git-scm.com/blog/2010/03/10/bundles.html) and [git bundle](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle).

Comment: Thanks! `git bundle` is something like packing the commits for sharing, but it needs extra commands to pack/unpack, and kinda hard to maintain while the repo itself is getter bigger. I'd like to use the method like `git daemon`, which improves the perf and remains simple.

Comment: For `git bundle`, you need to unpack the whole repo for the first time, after that you only need to bundle/unbundle for the new commits. And yeah, `git daemon` is also a good choice, if you don't want to bundle/unbundle each time, you can follow the way `git daemon`.

Comment: Okay. Thanks! Just found `receive-pack` option in `git daemon`, which allows my peers to write this repo. Cool!

Comment: Since you solved the problem, you can add/mark the answer. And it will help others who have similar questions.

Comment: Okay. Let me test both solutions and write down more details here.

Answer (score 2):

[`git daemon`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-daemon) works really well in this situation. Its performance is good, but lacks of security on Windows Server.

On server side, run the following command:

```
cd ~/Documents/All-My-Git-Repos/
git daemon --verbose --reuseaddr --export-all --enable=receive-pack --base-path=.
```

On client side, clone any repo like this:

```
git clone git://my-git-server-address/repo-folder-name repo-clone-name
```

While using this on Windows server, the firewall will prompt for permissions on Port 9418, which should be granted.

Comment: Thank you for this